# Update Package list in repository after motherboard change

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, repository

I just installed a new motherboard / microprocessor on my computer, I want to do an update to it using apt-get and I've tried to do it from the GUI as well.

the issue is the package list still have AMD (which is my previous motherboard) related packages and when I do the upgrade I get a 404 message with the list of the packages.

this is an example:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

what I'm thinking about is just to remove the packages from the repository, is that the correct approach? how do I delete those packages from the repository, and how do I update with the packages for the new motherboard?

**Edit:**

Just to narrow the issue, this is what happens:

when I do a repo update to install cinnamon on my computer as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon (I haven't run this yet)
```

the repo gets updated with an "AMD" packages which isn't correct because I updated to an intel motherboard, why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no

```
ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
```

this is why you are getting **404 Not Found**

there is `ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly`

Comment: what's the case for a stable version?

Comment: Unfortunately, Gwendal Le Bihan, the maintainer of the PPA, has taken the decision to stop support for ubuntu. Cinnamon desktop can be download from http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Qiana (.deb pacakge(s)) If any dependencies are needed, you could download these (.deb packages) from the same repository.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an old version of the package installed in your PC? If so try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove package
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install package
```

If you have an outdated Ubuntu OS you may update it by typing:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

JP

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to detect the drivers for Intel? Maybe you installed Ubuntu and it detected AMD at that time. On the GUI, go to settings->drivers and then search for the missing drivers and update them. Restart your PC and I think everything should be ok. Then you can type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

so that you get the cinnamon package.

JP